# Проблема воспроизведения видео на IOS используя фреймворк Flutter и плагин video_player

Tags: видео, flutter, dart

Использую плагин для просмотра видео video_player 0.10.9 + 1
Для андроид воспроизведение видео работает отлично без всяких подвисаний и подлагиваний.
Для IOS всё совсем печально, видео жутко тормозит и совсем картинка не обновляется, но звук играет. Случайным образом мне удалось выяснить зацепку - когда на странице с видео появляется рекламный банер, в котором присутсвует анимация то видео проигрывается отлично, а если банер без анимации или его вообще нет то жуткие тормоза. Получается что на иос для Воспроизведения видео нужно постоянно выполнять метод setState(). Я сделал вот так :

```js
_controller.addListener(() async {
      setState(() {

      });
```

И видео значительно лучше стало отображаться, но далеко не идеально но уже результат хороший. Всё таки хотелось обиться идельного воспроизведение видео. Кто нибудь поделитесь Вашими результаттами по воспроизведению видео на IOS используя этот плагин

Comment: 1. Вы проверяете в release? Так как `Warning: The video player is not functional on iOS simulators. An iOS device must be used during development/testing.`

Comment: 2. Вопросы про проблемы с плагинами [необходимо задавать авторам этих плагинов](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22p%3A+video_player%22), а не на StackOverflow.